# How to execute promise call sequentially for fetch api

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I have to call fetch api till it's response value is updated(response value will get updated only after a time period).
let p1 = fetch(url);
How to call to this fetch api by executing multiple promise sequentially till the response value is updated

I tried to achieve the same using infinite loop. But that did not work. How to achieve this using promise?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.  This can probably be answered quickly if you show the code.  Otherwise, it would require a whole textbook of how to properly use asynchronous  programming to guess how to fix your specific code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` and `await`:

```
(async function () { 
     while (true) {
         let p1 = await fetch(url);
         // Make your check on the response. For example:
         let obj = await p1.json();
         if (obj.someField == someValue) return something;
     }
})(); // Call the async function immediately
```

Answer (score 0):

@trincot nailed it with his answer. Here is a demo of his approach (I cheated a little bit: as my AJAX endpoint returns only static data I changed the request each time as `url+i`):

```js
const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";
(async function () { 
  for(let i=1;i<100;i++) { // limited to 99 tries...
   let obj = await fetch(url+i).then(r=>r.json());
   console.log(obj.name);
   if (obj.name.toLowerCase().includes("kurtis")) return obj;
  }
})().then(res=>{
  // to be executed after the object was found and returned in RES:
  console.log("the result is:",res);
});
```

Instead of `while` I used a `for` loop. This gives me an easy way of limiting the maximum number of tries (here: 99).